# How do I fetch data from an API using dart/flutter?

Tags: android, api, http, flutter, http-headers

I want to send a request to an API in the below format

```
curl --request POST \
     --header 'Authorization: Token <token-id>' \
     --header 'Content-type: application/json' \
     --data '{"files": [{"name": "filename", "content": "xyz"}]}' \
     --url 'https://sampleurl.com'
```

How to do that? 
I've seen various questions/posts but none worked for me.
P.S, I am new to Flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter makes this quite simple with the [http package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http). Here's a basic sample:

```
final String url = <your-url>; 

var body = {
  "param1Key": "param1Value", 
  "param2Key": "param2Value",
  };

var headers = {"Authorization": "Token <token-id>"};
var response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the http package in flutter. It provides anything you need to do networking and APIs.